# How to find number of days between a field date and current date using php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have been trying to find answer for my problem, unable to find one, Pl find below code where it works fine if the input date for $start is given. But when the same is done using a date field without time, it gives an error.

```
    <?php
    $start = new DateTime('2011-10-12');
    $today = new DateTime();
    $days = round(abs($today->format('U') - $start->format('U')) / (60*60*24));
    echo $days;
    ?>
```

It echos **146**.

But if I replace the **$start** with a **table field** like:

```
    $start = $demurage2[DC_date];
    echo $start;
    $today = new DateTime();
    $dcdate = round(abs($today->format('U') - $start->format('U')) / (60*60*24));
    echo $dcdate;
```

**Error:**
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /home/tech17/public_html/svga/invoice-detail.php on line 490

I have tried echo **only $start**, it shows the correct date from the table: **2012-01-17.**

Comment: What are the contents of $start in your second example? You're expecting it to be a DateTime object but if it's come straight from MySQL it's most likely a string in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: $start when echo, it gives correct date value from table : 2012-01-17, not sure if it is a string. In this case should i try converting again ?, I need to get just number of days at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $start is not an object of DateTime class in the second example, so of course it does not work. How is the date stored? Technically this might work, but it is highly dependent on what this $demurage2['DC_date'] value is.

```
$start=new DateTime($demurage2['DC_date']);
```

Comment: Hi Kristovaher, yes this is working, as rightly said by liquorvicar, in the first instance. Thanks guys.